# Поиск и замена ссылок через BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup

Хочу найти в файлах все внешние ссылки и заменить их на мою. Не могу заменить найденые ссылки, подскажите в чем проблема!

P.S. учусь писать на python, так что не бросайте в меня помидорами

```
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from datetime import datetime

os.chdir("/Users/user1/Desktop/test")
count = 0
start_time = datetime.now()
files = os.listdir(".")
ex_link = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
    for name in files:
        if name != ".DS_Store" and not name.endswith(".xml") and not name.endswith(".jpg") and not name.endswith(".png") \
                and not name.endswith(".gif") and not name.endswith(".GIF"):
            with open(os.path.join(root, name)) as fp:
                soup = bs(fp, 'html.parser')
                all_link = soup.findAll('a')
                for link in all_link:
                    link_href = link.get('href')
                    if link_href is not None:
                        if link_href.startswith(('http://', 'https://')):
                            link_separate_data = link_href.split('/')
                            good_link = str('http://' + link_separate_data[2])
                            ex_link.append(good_link)
                for one in ex_link:
                    print(str(soup).replace(one, "/"))

        ex_link = []
        count += 1
end_time = datetime.now()
print('Duration: {}'.format(end_time - start_time))
```

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под "заменить" - где заменить то? Если в файле, то нужно в новый файл записывать результат.

Comment: В ex_link я складываю все найденные ссылки в html. Вот эти ссылки я хочу заменить например на /. А на счёт записи результата в файл, буду переходить потом. Через принт я смотрю заменились ли ссылки, но я вижу что они на месте потому и задал здесь вопрос.